# Concerning warning when using "Geeza Pro" to typeset Arabic text

Tags: fontspec, mac, arabic

I'm trying to create a document with Arabic text on a Mac using the system font "Geeza Pro". Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=0.2in]{standalone}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{arabic}

\defaultfontfeatures[ArabicFont]{
  UprightFont = Geeza Pro Regular,
  Script = Arabic
}
\newfontfamily{\arabicfont}{ArabicFont}

\begin{document}

\emph{One Thousand and One Nights} (Arabic: \textarabic{أَلْفُ لَيْلَةٍ وَلَيْلَةٌ})
is a collection of folk tales.

\end{document}
```

Although I can't read Arabic, this seems to work based on visual inspection:
[image: One Thousand and One Nights]
Unfortunately, I'm seeing a concerning warning:

```
Package fontspec Warning: Font "Geeza Pro Regular" does not contain requested
(fontspec)                Script "Arabic".
```

The `fontspec` documentation makes it clear that you must specify `Script = Arabic` to get correct results. This apparently is not working. I'm concerned that, while this example might be correct, others will not be.

What should I do to fix the warning, or do I, in fact, need to worry about this at all?

Comment: Can you add a link to download the font for testing.

Comment: It's one of the system fonts for Mac OS, so I don't believe I can provide a download link.